# Laravel: Assets not working in Windows

Tags: windows, laravel

I have a Laravel project that works perfectly in Mac OS but in Windows it doesn't load any asset (images, css, js, fonts...).

When I go to an image directly I get theses...

Any idea?

[image: Image load]
[image: Response headers]

Comment: Open developer tools and post the response headers you get. This looks like the raw response displayed in the browser.

Comment: I can't see anything obvious. Maybe it's a line endings problem in your code? Check git settings or whatever you used to transfer the files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was MAMP. I uninstall it and install XAMP and everything it's OK.

Maybe some bad configuration in php.ini?